# Plot categorical x axis

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, categorical-data, scatter

I have a data set (shown in picture from excel):

[image]

and I want to make a scatter plot with the categories along the x-axis:

[image]

My current code is:

```
Mydata= readtable('D:\Download\Book1.xlsv');
y= Mydata.Group1;
x=Mydata.Y;
size= 50;
scatter (x,y,size,'magenta','filled','square');

hold on

y= Mydata.Group2;
scatter(x,y,size,'red','filled','d');

y= Mydata.Group3;
scatter(x,y,size,'b','filled','p');

y= Mydata.Group4;
scatter(x,y,size,'yellow','filled','h');

y=Mydata.Group5;
scatter(x,y,size,'k','filled','o');

hold off
```

With this current code, all data were plotted in one line not like in the picture. I also want to add an error bar for each data later. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please do not provide raw data as screenshots, but rather as text (in the form of a code block). The chart you provided looks like a bar plot with invisible bars. Take a look [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/102220) and [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/bar-chart-with-error-bars.html).

Comment: Searching "MATLAB categorical errorbar" in my favourite search engine gives quite a few useful results. Have you taken a look at those?

Comment: I want a scatter plot. Not bar plot. Sorry

Comment: works perfectly fine for me. Are you sure that `x = Mydata.Y` are real `categorials` and not e.g. strings?

Comment: @max Yes. it is a categorical data. It is actually a measurement data. That is why later, I will need to add an error bar. And also I will add another data for the reference data for every group. For example:  x = Mydata.Y.(category 1) has 5 data. All the 5 data have their own reference data that will be added later. The image graph is the preferrable. The coding works for me too. But all the 5 data align in one line for every category. I want it to be separated like in the image above.

Comment: OK, keep the focus on one question. To sum this up, you want to plot data on `x = 1` but not all, the next data should be not at `x = 1` althought yout plot it there (this is the essence to emphazise what you are asking for!). Quit the `categorial` and plot it on `x=1` and `x=1.1`,... and than change the `Tick` and the `TickLabel` to your categories

Comment: @max Thank you so much max. Why I didn't think of that before. It works for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to plot data points for a category and color them by series.

```
% generate numbers
X = rand(3,4);

cols = {'r','b','g'}
num_categories = size(X)(2);
num_series = size(X)(1);

labels = cell(num_categories,1)
legends = cell(num_series,1)

figure;
hold on;

% plot series
for i=1:num_series
  scatter(1:num_categories,X(i,:),cols{i})
  legends{i,1} = ['series ', num2str(i)];
end

% generate labels for categories
for i=1:num_categories
  labels{i,1} = ['category ', num2str(i)];
end

set(gca, 'xtick',1:num_categories)
set(gca, 'xticklabel', labels)
axis([0, num_categories+1, 0, 1]);
legend(legends)
```

Can you elaborate what you mean with error bars and where you would want them to be? Do you want errors per category and series?